# What is the default value of a map of struct

Tags: go, struct, initialization, default-value, go-map

What is the default value of struct in a map? How to check the map value is initialized?

```
type someStruct struct { 
    field1 int
    field2 string
}
var mapping map[int]someStruct

func main() {
    mapping := make(map[int]someStruct)
}

func check(key int) {
    if mapping[key] == ? {}
}
```

Should I check against `nil` or `someStruct{}`?

Comment: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/22

Comment: This is covered in the language spec too: every type has a [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value), and for an [index expression] `mapping[key]` the value is the zero value of the type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Default value of a struct is zero value for each field which is different on basis of its type.

> When storage is allocated for a variable, either through a
>   declaration or a call of new, or when a new value is created, either
>   through a composite literal or a call of make, and no explicit
>   initialization is provided, the variable or value is given a default
>   value. Each element of such a variable or value is set to the zero
>   value for its type: false for booleans, 0 for numeric types, "" for
>   strings, and nil for pointers, functions, interfaces, slices,
>   channels, and maps. This initialization is done recursively, so for
>   instance each element of an array of structs will have its fields
>   zeroed if no value is specified.

```
type T struct { i int; f float64; next *T }
t := new(T)
```

the following holds:

```
t.i == 0
t.f == 0.0
t.next == nil
```

But for checking the value of a map based on the key if it exists you can use it as:

```
i, ok := m["route"]
```

In this statement, the first value (i) is assigned the value stored under the key "route". If that key doesn't exist, i is the value type's zero value (0). The second value (ok) is a bool that is true if the key exists in the map, and false if not.

For your question

> Should I check against nil or someStruct{} ?

To check for initialized empty struct you can check for `someStruct{}` as:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type someStruct struct { 
    field1 int
    field2 string
}
var mapping map[int]someStruct

func main() {
    var some someStruct
    fmt.Println(some == (someStruct{}))
    //mapping := make(map[int]someStruct)
}
```

[Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8XuBLB245xu)